# changing value of a variable inside catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

Here's the code:

```
public static String removeDateFromString(String txt) {
    String dateRemovedString = new String();
    String[] str = txt.split("-");

    for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
        try {
            format.parse(str[i]);
        } catch(ParseException e) {
            dateRemovedString.concat(str[i]);
        }
    }
    return dateRemovedString;
}
```

For,

input text:`Cricket Match - 01 Jul`

output text:`""` (empty String)

But I want, output:`Cricket Match`

What should I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

String is [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html):

> Note: The String class is immutable, so that once it is created a
>   String object cannot be changed. The String class has a number of
>   methods, some of which will be discussed below, that appear to modify
>   strings. Since strings are immutable, what these methods really do is
>   create and return a new string that contains the result of the
>   operation.

```
dateRemovedString = dateRemovedString.concat(str[i]);
```

---

StringBuilder is mutable. StringBuilder is used to **build** a String. Use StringBuilder instead in this case. Example usage:

```
StringBuilder dateRemovedString = new StringBuilder();
dateRemovedString.append(str[i]);
return dateRemovedString.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the input text format, then don't bother to hit the exception.

Simply extract the part you are interested using split or RegExp and then process it